# Is there a way to dump a thousand images somewhere and extract them using REST Api?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Here is the thing:-

I have over a thousand images saved locally in my mac. I have a landing page that mocks an ecommerce deal site. It would be tedious to have to manually type in the src url in the img tag for a thousand pictures. Thus, i thought i could somehow have this images dumped in a cloud storage or something and use REST api get method to extract these images in a response.data. Then assign it to a $scope variable and use ng-repeat to bind the images in my landing page view. Is this possible? If not, what are the alternatives? SQL database?

Appreciate your help. P.S. I am totally a beginner at web development.

Comment: There are hundreds of ways of doing this, but looks like you're on the right track.   Take a look at the node aws SDK, should make this easy.

Comment: Hey i did try using the node AWS sdk. But i was only able to add one file in one bucket. And i dont think a .jpg in the keyName works. Not sure if i have t convert it or something. I used the demo sample code as shown below: -

Comment: var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

// Create an S3 client
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

// Create a bucket and upload something into it
var bucketName = 'node-sdk-sample-' + uuid.v4();
var keyName = 'akshar_amazon.txt';

s3.createBucket({Bucket: bucketName}, function() {
  var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: 'Akshar is awesome!'};
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err)
    else
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
  });
});

Comment: .jpg in the keyname works just fine.   What framework are you using?

Try using the examples in this repo for angular file upload.

Comment: I am using the angular framework but I will follow your suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `node.js`.  It's Javascript for a server which should make it pretty easy since you already know Javascript.

On a Mac, you can install node like this:

```
brew install node
```

Use this node.js code (credit to [codepedia.com](http://www.codexpedia.com/node-js/node-js-http-server-displaying-images-from-a-directory/), tweaked a little by me):

```
//include http, fs and url module
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    url = require('url');
    imageDir = './images/';

//create http server listening on port 3333
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //use the url to parse the requested url and get the image name
    var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
        pic = query.image;

    if (typeof pic === 'undefined') {
        getImages(imageDir, function (err, files) {
            var imageList = JSON.stringify(files);
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'application/json'});
            res.end(imageList);
        });
    } else {
        //read the image using fs and send the image content back in the response
        fs.readFile(imageDir + pic, function (err, content) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(400, {'Content-type':'text/html'})
                console.log(err);
                res.end("No such image");    
            } else {
                //specify the content type in the response will be an image
                res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':'image/jpg'});
                res.end(content, "binary");
            }
        });
    }

}).listen(3333);
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:3333/");

//get the list of jpg files in the image dir
function getImages(imageDir, callback) {
    var fileType = '.jpg',
        files = [], i;
    fs.readdir(imageDir, function (err, list) {
        for(i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
            if(path.extname(list[i]) === fileType) {
                files.push(list[i]); //store the file name into the array files
            }
        }
        callback(err, files);
    });
}
```

Run this from the command line to start you new image server (assuming you named the file "server.js"):

```
node server.js
```

You should see this text appear on the command line:

```
Server running at http://localhost:3333/
```

You can quickly test it by going to this address in your browser and you should see a JSON object showing you an array of all the filenames in the "./images" directory.  By the way, this program assumes you're putting the images folder in the same directory as "server.js".  You can put the images directory anywhere and just change the path of the variable "imageDir".

Now you can load the list of files from Angular using this code in your controller:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:3333", function(data) {
    $scope.images = data;
});
```

In your view, you can now use an `ng-repeat` like this to display all the images:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images" style="padding: 8px">
    <img src="http://localhost:3333/image={{ image }}">
</div>
```

Note: this will work if you run it locally on your Mac or if you upload all the images to a server on which you can use Node.js.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response Dr.Cool. I will follow the above suggestions.

Comment: If you think this either solves your problem or gets you started in the right direction, can you mark my answer with the checkmark? Thanks.